# Inserting data into temporary tables in PostgreSQL is significantly slower compared to Oracle

Tags: oracle, postgresql, performance

Our application supports multiple databases including Oracle and PostgreSQL. In several use-cases, multiple queries are run to fetch necessary data. The data obtained from one or more queries is filtered based on business logic, and the filtered data is then inserted into a temporary table using a parameterized INSERT statement. This temporary table is then joined with other tables in a subsequent query. We have noticed that time taken for inserting data into temporary table linearly increases with the number of rows inserted with PostgreSQL database. This temporary table has only one varchar column of 15 bytes size. Inserting 80 rows takes 16ms, 160 rows takes 32ms, 280 rows takes 63ms, and so on. The same operations with Oracle database take about 1 ms for these inserts.

We are using PostgreSQL 10.4 with psqlODBC driver 10.03 version. We have configured temp_buffers (256MB), shared_buffers (8GB), work_mem (128MB) and maintenance_work_mem (512MB) parameters based on the guidelines provided in PostgreSQL documentation.

Are there any other configuration options we could try to improve the performance of temp table inserts in PostgreSQL database? Please suggest.

Comment: So,your round-trip delay is 200us. That includes at least 4 system calls/context switches.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really identified the temporary table as the problem.

For example, below is a quick test of inserts to a 15 *character* (not the same as bytes of course) varchar column

`=> CREATE TEMP TABLE tt (vc varchar(15));
CREATE TABLE
=> \timing on
Timing is on.
=> INSERT INTO tt SELECT to_char(i, '0000000000') FROM generate_series(1,100) i;
INSERT 0 100
Time: 0.758 ms`

This is on my cheap, several years old laptop. Unless you are running your PostgreSQL database on a Raspberry Pi then I don't think temporary table speed is a problem for you.

Comment: Presumably, the OP is firing `INSERT INTO x (...) VALUES(...)` statements - one row at a time. (or excuting them on a prepared statement) So he is mostly measuring the network latency.

Comment: @wildplasser - The data is inserted into temporary table using a single prepared statement with a bind parameter. The data is bound to this bind parameter. We are not using multiple INSERT INTO statements. Is it possible that psqlODBC driver is not inserting all values in one go, but one at a time?

Comment: Yes, of course. The ODBC-driver only relays the *messages*, (and the replies), one by one: {prepare,reply, execute,reply,execute,reply,...}

Comment: @wildplasser - Thank you for the clarification. Please let me know if there are alternative options that can be pursued to do a bulk insert using the ODBC driver.

Comment: At Richard: I ran your script on a Raspberry Pi, and it took 7.2ms (1.4 ms on my desktop machine) Both from inet and after pre-warm

Comment: @RichardHuxton - The PostgreSQL database is running on a SuSE Linux 12SP1 VM with 32GB RAM. You are correct that the problem is not specific to temporary tables, I am seeing the same problem with unlogged tables as well. Due to the nature of our application, we need to insert data into the temp tables using INSERT INTO with VALUES clause.